# Unconfirmed transaction and expired address help

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, blockchain, address, transaction-fees

I have one unconfirmed transaction and now the expired address. I cannot abandon the transition because the writing is gray, +24h hours have passed (the arrival was expected in 8 hours...) and no command works.

How can i cancel the sending and resend the bitcoins?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is this Bitcoin Core? Right click it to increase the fees.

Comment: But there is a problem, the address to whom i sent the Bitcoins has expired because they did not arrive in the time required by that site. What happens if i increase the rates?

Comment: Contact the website. If you increase the rates they might be able to refund them more easily.

Comment: How can i delete the unconfirmed transaction and have a refund?

Comment: That's not possible. You can either increase thee fee or wait until the unconfirmed transactions decrease and yours is accepted.

Comment: Hi @BitDude, please note that the earlier replies to your question in which an answerer tried to get to contact you in private were likely an attempt to defraud you out of more money. Please be careful about what information you provide to that individual and which advice by them you follow, if you contacted them.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to tell us what software or service you are using?

Comment: @Murch i knew he was a scammer, he had a newly created account and the email is bogus just to cheat. I don't fall for it easily.

Comment: I solved by myself.